# How to orient an emission based on the emitter

Tags: modeling, rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, particles

I am trying to render a house, with bricks as the walls, and tiles as the roof. im using an emitter with a face hexagonal grid. the problem im having is that the brick object keeps its orientation, and i would like it to rotate depending on the object its emitting from.

Note: i placed the bricks in this example to demonstrate what i want, the house currently looks like the first example.

This is what it currently looks like:
[image: the bricks are keeeping the objects orientation]

what i would like it to look like:
[image: bricks are orienting themselves to be parallel with the objects face]